# Separate 1 column into 2 columns in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I'm trying to separate 1 column into 2 columns in a database table that I have. I've found questions on here that give you direction in terms of SELECTing the data, but not doing the insert itself.

[image: Table name = fruit]

As is clear from the picture above, I'm trying to separate ID into first and second. Can someone give me a hand in doing the insert? I have the SELECT statement as follows:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',id) > 0  
         THEN SUBSTRING(id,1,2) 
         ELSE id end first,

    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',id)>0 
    THEN SUBSTRING(id,CHARINDEX('.',id)+1,len(id))  
     ELSE NULL END second
FROM fruit
```

[EDIT: there are other columns in the table]

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for here is an UPDATE rather than an INSERT (whereas the rows your trying to set this data for already exist...INSERT would create an entirely new row).

```
 UPDATE fruit
      SET first = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',id) > 0  THEN SUBSTRING(id,1,2) 
                  ELSE id
                  END,
          second =  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',id)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(id,CHARINDEX('.',id)+1,len(id))  
                    ELSE NULL 
                    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
create  table t_split(id varchar(20),first varchar(20),second varchar(20))

insert into t_split values('AB.11','','');
insert into t_split values('AB.22','','');
insert into t_split values('AB.33','','');
insert into t_split values('AB.44','','');
insert into t_split values('AB.55','','');
insert into t_split values('ABt.557','','');
```

SELECT * FROM t_split

```
UPDATE t_split SET first=LEFT(ID,2),second =RIGHT(ID,2) WHERE ID IS NOT NULL;
```

OR

```
UPDATE t_split
SET first = LEFT(id,CHARINDEX('.',id)-1),second = RIGHT(id,LEN(id)-CHARINDEX('.',id))
```

OR

```
UPDATE t_split
SET first = LEFT(id,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(id))-1) ,second = RIGHT(ID,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(id))-1)
```

Comment: Great effort, than you. @DarkSolace gave me the goods above, but I appreicate you taking the time to answer! Thanks!